# Want @XmlRootElement in classes generated by jaxb2-maven-plugin

Tags: java, maven, jaxb, wsdl

I have one set of Java classes generated from a WSDL that work fine; I'm adding another WSDL to the project for another webservice I'm using, but I get no @XmlRootElement annotations in the generated classes from the second WSDL, and don't understand why not.

Here's the plugin portion of the pom:

```
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
          <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.2</version>
          <executions>
              <execution>
                  <id>xjc</id>
                  <goals>
                      <goal>xjc</goal>
                  </goals>
              </execution>
          </executions>
          <configuration>
              <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
              <sources>
                  <source>${resources.path}my-module/src/main/resources/wsdl/w1.wsdl</source>
                  <source>${resources.path}my-module/src/main/resources/wsdl/w2.wsdl</source>
              </sources>
              <extension>true</extension>
              <xjbSources>
                  <xjbSource>src/main/resources/xjb/bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
              </xjbSources>
          </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

And here's bindings.xjb:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jxb:bindings version="1.0" xmlns:jxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc= "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <jxb:bindings>
        <!-- annotate tag here? -->
        <jxb:globalBindings>
            <xjc:simple/>
        </jxb:globalBindings>
    </jxb:bindings>
</jxb:bindings>
```

I read in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18665053/generating-java-classes-using-maven-jaxb2-plugin) SO post about using an `annotate` tag, so I inserted

```
        <annox:annotate>
            <annox:annotate annox:class="javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement" />
        </annox:annotate>
```

at the indicated place in the bindings.xjb file, but of course I don't have a definition for the `annox` prefix, so that doesn't work. The post doesn't indicate where that's defined.

I've also been through multiple answers in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819720/no-xmlrootelement-generated-by-jaxb) SO post; unfortunately the various methods each leave out some steps. For instance, I'm willing to call marshall and unmarshall methods directly, but I need to know where to get the "JAXBContext" they speak of, and what the unmarshall call looks like, or where to look it up.

Is `annox` the correct way to do this? Is there another correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you post w1/w2.wsdl (maybe in simplified form)?

Comment: @ScottKurz Will be happy to, but it will have to wait until Monday (Eastern US Time); just tried to get into my work computer and there's something wrong with the login sequence...

Comment: the simplest way for jaxb2-maven-plugin is here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10613686

Answer (score 3):

I just got done converting to from the old jaxb2-maven-plugin that is a dependency of only 1 other project in Maven to maven-jaxb2-plugin which is a dependency for 18. There seems to be much more documentation for it. Check out the [JAXB2 Maven Plugin Wiki](https://github.com/highsource/maven-jaxb2-plugin/wiki#quick-start)

Here is a pom.xml example:

```
<build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>0.13.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>generate</id>
        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>generate</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
      <schemaDirectory>src/main/resources/</schemaDirectory>
      <generateDirectory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxb</generateDirectory>
      <schemaIncludes>
        <include>MyXSD.xsd</include>
      </schemaIncludes>
      <schemaExcludes>
        <include>ObeXSD.xsd</include>
      </schemaExcludes>
      <args>
        <arg>-Xannotate</arg>
      </args>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-annotate</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2</version>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
  <plugin>
      <inherited>true</inherited>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
          <source>1.7</source>
          <target>1.7</target>
      </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Here is an example xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    jaxb:version="2.1" 
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net" 
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="annox">
    <xsd:complexType name="AbstractProblemClass" abstract="true">
    <xsd:sequence />
    </xsd:complexType>

    <xsd:complexType name="ConcreteClass">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <annox:annotate target="class">@javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement</annox:annotate>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
    <xsd:complexContent>
        <xsd:extension base="AbstractProblemClass">
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element name="Stuff" type="xsd:String" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:complexContent>
    </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

For jakarta based annotations (Spring Boot 3 uses them eg) this one worked for me:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.xml.bind-api</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb2-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${jaxb2-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>xjc</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <verbose>true</verbose>
                        <packageName>package.name</packageName>
                        <sourceType>wsdl</sourceType>
                        <xjbSources>
                            <xjbSource>src/main/resources/bindings.xjb</xjbSource>
                        </xjbSources>
                        <sources>
                            <source>src/main/resources/wsdl/some.wsdl</source>
                        </sources>
                        <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/</outputDirectory>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

bindings.xjb file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?> <jxb:bindings version="3.0" xmlns:jxb="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/jaxb"
              xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
              jxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc">
    <jxb:globalBindings>
        <xjc:simple/> <!-- adds @XmlRootElement annotations -->
    </jxb:globalBindings> </jxb:bindings>
```

Comment: I have tried this, but somehow it was not working for complex types